# Webpack ts-loader ignores type changes with hot module replacement

Tags: webpack, hot-module-replacement, ts-loader

I have a simple webpack configuration with: **ts-loader** and **hot module replacement**. When I make a type change I get an **TS2322** error, and when I fixed it ( and all files from IDE are marked as "error-free" ) I still get the error from above. If I restart webpack it's working as expected. I don't want to use **transpileOnly: true** because I want to detect all type errors.

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
{
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    'babel-loader',
    'ts-loader'
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
]
...
```

**some/path/name/test.interface.tsx** - before - with **TS2322** error

```
export default interface Test {
  name: number;
  value: number;
}
```

> [**tsl**] ERROR in {name: number; value: number} is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly < PropsWithChildren < Test >>'.
>    TS2322: Type **'string'** is not assignable to type **'number'**.

**some/path/name/test.interface.tsx** - after - with same **TS2322** error from above

```
export default interface Test {
  name: string; // changed type, from number to string
  value: number;
}
```

If I restart webpack, the type error is not showing anymore in the terminal.

Comment: hi mate, did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry: try this https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/issues/36